Is the Mach cone the model of a shockwave?
I am in the process of writing a mathematics paper which aims to model the interaction of a supersonic (or transonic for that matter) object with a flat plane. I need to determine the shape that a supersonic object's propagated shockwave forms.
When doing my research, I came across the concept of a "Mach Cone" and am now not sure if that is the way that the shockwave propagates through the fluid or not. I would much appreciate any help on the matter.

Yes, a Mach cone is a possible model of a shock front.  However, its shape greatly depends on the shape of the piston/driver.  For instance, if you have sphere, it would not be cone-shaped but more like a hyperboloid of two-sheets.

If I take a point into consideration, will it be a cone?

Well if you zoom out enough then yes, the overall shape can be cone-like, I suppose.
